# How can mongoose automatically generate another set of Id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongoDB for storing data .I have create a user schema .
The idea is ,apart from the mongodb automatic generate _id ,I will still need another automatic generate publish_id for showing to users(between:10-12) . The question is: how can I make it ?
Thank you so much for your help !!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nanoid. You have to install it with `npm i nanoid`. It will create you a random unique id.

In your controller when you are creating a new user, requires nanoid and then just use it. You can pass as parameter the length you want the id have. For exmaple: `nanoid(48)`